# Autoincrement in pairs in QGIS

Tags: qgis, autoincrement

Is there a way to count in pairs in attribute table? For example to be attribute like that: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 and so on, or 1,3,5,7.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *Field Calculator* with the expression `@row_number*2` to insert an attribute with values 2, 4, 6, ... if this is what you're looking for. Alternatively use `@row_number*2 - 2` if you want to start at zero or `@row_number*2 - 1` if you want to start at one.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Nice! As you're new here (like me), you can also check out [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)